# In Swift, LinearGradient and Form - Background overlapped

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have question about the linear-gradient background which is (I believe) under the native background of Form. Please let me know how to change the Form's background OR the proper way to display that linear-gradient background. Thanks.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            ZStack {
                
                BackgroundColorSetup(colorTop: .black,colorBottom: Color.theme.accent)
               
                Form {
                    Section {
                        Text("Hello, world!")
                            .padding()
                        Text("Hello, world!")
                            .padding()
                   }
                }
            }
                .navigationBarTitle("Pay Split", displayMode: .inline)
                .accentColor(Color.theme.accent)
        }

    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct BackgroundColorSetup: View {
    var colorTop: Color
    var colorBottom: Color
    var body: some View {
        LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [colorTop,
                                                   colorBottom]),
                       startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

I tried to use

```
   init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.theme.alternate)
    }
```

It works. But It is single color.  And I need the linear gradient color.

Comment: Form { ... }.background(...)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have your background color on a ZStack behind your form, you can use this

```
init() {
    UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(Color.clear)
}
```

this will make the background of your form transparent and show your gradient. With this init() you can either have your background in the ZStack or add it on the `form {}.background()`

Comment: Thanks. It works. By the way, what is the difference of using UIColor(Color.clear) and .clear in this case ?

Comment: I wrote it fast and i'm more use to Color than UIColor but you should actually use `.clear`, the only difference is using a Color instead of UIColor but the result is pretty much the same.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much.